# How do I call GetAsyncKeyState() from somewhere other than main

Tags: c++

Hello so I am making a small game just to experiment, I am new to c++ so I'm just learning, and when i called GetAsyncKeyState() from a function in another class I got the error `GetAsyncKeyState() was not declared in this scope` but when i call it from main it runs fine I've  been staring at it for a while and decided to come here since I was always helped when I ask other questions, if you can help great but if you can't at leased you tried. Thanks.

Comment: It's like any other external function. Include the appropriate header and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is declared in windows.h, so that must be #include'd in any file that makes the call.

Answer (score 0):

add this code to first line of your code :

```
 #include <windows.h>
```

it ll solve everything

Comment: How does this add anything new to the [answer given over 7 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24703498/10871073)?